# How to switch signal enhancements (on/off) from settings in Default Device in sound settings to right click context menu

Tags: audio, context-menu

The title says it all I have a headphone that sometimes requires signal enhancements to be turned on or off. would that be possible? Thanks

[image: Screenshot of the item I want to add to the right-click context menu]

Comment: Which context menu are you referring to?

Comment: The desktop context menu. Where you click right mouse button on your wallpaper